# Use application cache only when offline

Tags: javascript, php, html, backbone.js, cache-manifest

I have used html5 manifest to store a web app offline. I only want the offline version of the app to load when there isn't an internet connection. When there is an internet connection i want to be able to run directly offline. Is this possible?

Comment: you can double code everything into network and fallback groups, but that kinda defeats the point of appCache... why do you want to use live  urls instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found couple of links that might be useful for you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5
http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: I only want the the manifest to kick in when the user doesn't have a live internet connection so they get partial use of the app. When the user is online it's best for it to run natively.